# Interesting behavior of method binding with generics

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

I am learning Generics, and while learning come across  a  sample code which, according to me should print`'ok'`

However i am getting following excetpion.

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Test$B cannot be 
     cast to java.util.Collection
```

Can some one help me on this behavior.

```
public class Test {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <U extends B> U get() {
        return (U) new B();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A<B> a = new A<>(get());
    }

    static class A<T> {
        A(Collection<? extends T> lst) {
            System.out.println("Bad constructor");
        }

        A(T e) {
            System.out.println("ok");
        }
    }

    static class B {
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: When I run your code, `ok` is printed in the console. Did you provide the correct code?

Comment: Please check again i tried again but getting same error.

Comment: In Eclipse Neon.3 I get the `ClassCastException`.  If I change it to `B b = get(); A<B> a = new A<>(b);` it works. This could be a corner case where compile time binding behaves unintuitively, or is broken.

Comment: I am also using eclipse Neon 3 , So are you saying i should check my eclipse version.

Comment: What JDK do you have installed.  I'm using 8.0_121

Comment: Please check the screen shot i am using same as you are using :(

Comment: Interesting. Changing it to `A<B> a = new A<>((B) get());` also causes it to work (prints `ok`).  I can't think of a reason why it would bind to the first constructor at compile time.

Comment: So our results agree with 8.0_121.  Possibly a bug?

Comment: Funny behaviour. I just compiled it with javac 1.8.0_72 and get the `ClassCastException` when I execute it. With eclipse 4.4.2, everything runs fine

Comment: So shall i close this discussion... :(